# Window in Adobe Photoshop too large for my screen

Tags: windows-vista, adobe-photoshop

Adobe Photoshop's **File → Save for Web & Devices** opens a "dialog window" which looks like this:

[image]

[<kbd>**Enlarge**</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMOM5.png)

On my laptop with a maximum screen resolution of 1280*720, the "dialog window" is simply too big for the screen to show it fully. We can see that parts of the dialog window are simply not displayed:

[image]

[<kbd>**Enlarge**</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J8Qk.jpg)

The "dialog window" doesn't seem to be resizable. Is there any way to "scroll" through this "dialog window"?

Alternatively, is there a way to set the dialog window to a smaller size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That window cannot be re-sized, you really need to be running at a higher resolution. I'm guessing that's not really an option, though, so instead just auto-hide your Windows Task Bar:

1. Right click anywhere on the task bar
   (the big grey bar at the bottom of
   your screen).
2. Select "Properties".
3. In the window that opens tick
   "Auto-hide the task bar".

That way you'll be able to see the contents of that window in Photoshop.

Comment: Unless the window can be re-sized, or easily moved, I'm afraid so :(

Comment: Ok, but this seems to be a stopgap fix that wouldn't work if the screen height was smaller by another 10 pixels...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is related to the resolution in a lower/higher resolution it may not appear.

I used another trick,

1. Just right click on task bar> uncheck Lock Taskbar
2. Drag the task bar in the right or left side of your monitor.

And then you can easily see the SAVE button and other things.

Comment: Ok, but having to re-align the taskbar every time I use this feature would be a real hassle...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Windows 7, you can press the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>.  This will stretch the window to the top and bottom of the screen.

Comment: the shortcut doesn't work for me, I'm using windows vista home premium

Answer (score 1):

Just drag the image around so you can check all of it. The "Save for website" feature is not designed for large images. (For larger images you can preview what the output will look like by making sure the "Preview" checkbox is ticked when saving as .JPG, etc.)

Hope that's clear. In short: You can't resize that window, you have to drag the image around in it with the Hand tool.

Comment: Ok, see my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you have left is the real estate the windows taskbar is using. Maybe the auto-hide will give you enough.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Show-or-hide-the-taskbar

Sadly, Adobe made that window a bit big for your resolution.

Comment: so if something gets even bigger than my autohide taskbar i'd run out of luck?

Comment: Yep - I don't think many graphics developers are expecting that resolution anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This window can't be changed or resized because it's a dialog box opened after clicking *Save for web devices*.

When you select this option you can't edit anything in the back, so this window comes up for saving your image with optimizations.

There is nothing you can do about the resolution or anything else. It's normal.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and it is because of the screen resolution and I have never ran across any way to fix it. For me however, I just look and make sure the part that I can see has the settings right, I make sure when I put it all together things were good to go, so then despite not seeing the save button, it is already highlighted and only requires I hit the enter button. Thats been working for me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As the sizes are probably set to 'automatic'
go to  preferences,
then to Interface,
and then set 'UI Scaling' to i.e. 100%.

This way everything in Photoshop will be a lot smaller, maybe a bit too small, but check it out.

Hope this helps

Comment: Perhaps someone can verify this.. Photoshop is too expensive. I don't have it now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your screen resolution to a higher number.

Comment: it's currently at the highest I can set it to 1280x720

Comment: Okay, then it must be a limitation of your monitor or video card. You can try updating your video drivers or try using less than 32bpp color settings to see if it gives you more resolution. Otherwise, for the long term, you may want to upgrade. For the short term, see Kara Marfia's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Display settings. Make sure you select the monitor you have the dialog window open in, then change your scale and layout %. Once you select a new % amount, the dialog box should adjust to your screen. I was able to switch my scale and layout % back to the original % I had it on originally after the dialog box adjusted.